# Como sobreescribo un fichero .txt en android?

Tags: java, android

en mi APP recibo a través de un `socket` un `String` periodicamente. Necesito guardar solamente el último String recibido pero con las funciones que he conseguido voy añadiendo filas y Strings al fichero. Como puedo sobreescribir el fichero cada vez que reciba las coordenadas para tener solo las últimas? 
destruir el fichero y volverlo a crear no me parece una solución muy limpia, hay alguna forma de simplemente escribir encima? 
Os dejo las que tengo creadas actualmente:

Crear fichero si no existe:

```
protected boolean crearSiNoExiste(String nombreFichero, String contenido){
        file = new File(getFilesDir(), nombreFichero);
        Log.d("log1", nombreFichero);
//Si el Fichero no existe se crea con una entrada inicial
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try{
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                out.write(contenido.getBytes());
                out.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Creada categoría " + nombreFichero, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();a
            }catch (IOException e){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error creando categoría", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

El cual comprueba si existe el fichero y de no ser así lo crea.

El siguiente es para añadir una linea al fichero, es el que quiero modificar para que lo sobreescriba todo:

```
protected boolean Entrada(){
//Comprobar que no hay ningún EditText vacío
        if (categoria.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No hay nombre de categoría", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter fout = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    openFileOutput(nomFichero, Context.MODE_APPEND));
            fout.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            fout.write(categoria.getText().toString()); //Escribir término en inglés
            fout.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error añadiendo categoría", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: entra aqui y echale un vistazo a la documentacion del metodo "openFileOutput" https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_APPEND , creo que cambiando el MODE_APPEND podrias hacer lo que quieres, aunque tambien podrias crear otro archivo y guardarlo con el mismo nombre en lugar de abrir el existente y editar el contenido no?

Comment: Es una opción, al guardarlo con el mismo nombre el otro desaparecerá? Si es así podria hacerlo facilmente.